# What is the expression for translational kinetic energy of REAL GAS?

Tags: kinetic-theory

I know that  the translational kinetic energy of ideal gas is $\dfrac{3}{2} nRT$.

What is the expression/formula for translational  kinetic energy of a real gas ?
Does it change due to potential energy interaction in real gas which is not present in ideal gas?
Does it remain the same as $\dfrac{3}{2} nRT$ ?
Does it varies from one real gas to another ?
What are the new factors that affect it if it  is different from that of ideal gas?
I am a high school student.

Comment: Please do not ask the same question twice: [Is expression for law of equipartion of energy valid for real gas?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/563623/is-expression-for-law-of-equipartion-of-energy-valid-for-real-gas)

Comment: So you mean to say that translational kinectic energy of real gas and ideal gas are same?

Comment: If it is not ,can you get give me the expression for translation   kinetic energy of real gas

Comment: I am pretty much confused right now, pleasee help me out.

Comment: This question will probably be closed very soon, because it does not satisfy the standard. This side is not about helping a single person, but to answer questions, which help others as well. So my advice is that you use your second question (linked above) and try to be much more specific. E.g. state in which element you interested in? Show a plot for the heat capacity at const. volume, and include the ideal gas result. Structure your question and show us at which point you are confused.

Comment: Thanks for your advice.But I think my question is straightforward. Just asking for the expression for translation kinetic energy for real gas. If the expression for ideal gas kinetic energy is 3/2 nRt. You could have answered me in just one line . I think if your answer helps me it will help others too.So start by helping the person who is asking you the doubt directly!